# When i update angular.cli.json file, webpack is not compiled automatically

Tags: angular

When I add bootstrap css in angular.cli.json, wepack is not compiling. Changes not reflected in front end.
I restarted the server, but the issue remains.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Could we get a peek at the error from webpack?

Comment: No i didnt get any error. Bootstrap style sheet is not reflected in front end

Comment: can you post your styles from angular-cli.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you changed angular-cli.json you need to restart `ng serve` or do new `ng build` depending on what you're need. It doesn't watch for configuration changes in the realtime, only for file changes.